# Modal pop up is not showing when we load second time

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a modal popup on button when we click first time it works fine but when we click in second time it not open third time again open. in second time display:none are calling but first,third display:block are calling

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="pages-title" style="font-size:24px;">
            Plan your Dream Wedding with us

        </div>
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="2437" title="Home"]' ); ?>        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check why second time display:none is coming. And share your code for opening and closing

Comment: Please show you button action coding

Comment: @Kaushik first time this one to go <div class="modal fade open in" id="myModal" style="z-index: 1003; display: block; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1); top: 10%;">

second time this one to go  <div class="modal fade open" id="myModal" style="z-index: 1003; display: none; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1); top: 10%;">

Comment: @SAVe <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>

Comment: what about 2nd time? update the code in the question.

Comment: @SAVe when i remove the bootstrap.min.js file from the footer its work fine but then side bar not working

Comment: @Kaushik Please take a look for my last comment

Comment: because of some reason in your code, the second time the value of `display` is set to `none`. Because of that it is not showing. Show your code where you're trying to open the modal. have you added `$('#myModal').modal('show')`

Comment: Please do not write parts of your question in these comments. Complete your question so that it becomes possible to give you an answer.

Comment: @Kaushik i tried to add $('#myModal').modal('show') but it's not working

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thankyou so much for your advice

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)